# How to add another property to big JSON object in firebase real time database

Tags: json, firebase, react-native, firebase-realtime-database, mobile-development

I'm looking to add a new property to a higher level (main level, I forget the terminology) of the json tree in my firebase real time database. I usually make my edits through the console. I've been able to add new properties at deeper levels but going up the json tree the console doesn't let me by saying: `Read-only & non-realtime mode activated in the data viewer to improve browser performance
Select a key with fewer records to edit or view in realtime`

I thought about exporting, adding, then importing again (I've done this before at lower levels) but this seems a little scary having to essentially reimport the database just to add a new property. I've read the docs and they suggest using set method. How is this normally done?

Answer (score 0):

I was able to figure this out. 
You can use the browser URL to create a new node in the json tree if you cannot do it in the console because of it's offline mode.

Just enter the node name in to URL as if you were going to an already existing url and it'll get added

example: http://www..com/newnode